# Execute OPERATION (plus, minus, multiply, divide) in Update SQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to execute plus, minus, multiply or divide operation in SQL to the selected table and row?

Below is example code where I manually minus original quantity to create a new quantity and update into the selected row:

```
$idArr = $_POST['checkboxId'];

foreach($idArr as $index=>$value)
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

    // Get Quantity from this item id
    $sql = "SELECT quantity FROM items WHERE item_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];

    // New quantity after minus by 1
    $new_quantity = $row['quantity'] - 1;

    // Update new quantity to this item
    $sql = "UPDATE items SET quantity = '$new_quantity' WHERE item_id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Is it a practical way to update changes of quantity(integer) in preferred rows?
Can I do that with a single update query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973380/sql-how-to-increase-or-decrease-one-for-a-int-column-in-one-command

Comment: You could do it wit one UPDATE statement - 'UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE item_id = '$id'

Comment: Thank you guys, I never came across about this. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just put the operation in the SQL `update` query ?

For example, you could have a query such as this one :

```
UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE item_id = '$id'
```

Or :

```
UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE item_id = '$id'
```

Great advantage : this is done in a single SQL query *(no `select`, and, then, `update`)* ; which means there will be no problem if two users try to do this at the exact same time : SQL will deal with concurrency, and do one query after the other.

With your initial solution, you could have *(if you're pretty unlucky -- but this happens)* :

- first user does a `select`, gets 5 as quantity
- second user does a `select`, gets 5 as quantity
- first user `update`s to 4
- second user `update`s to 4 too... but, there, it should have been updated to 3 !

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$sql = "UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE item_id = '$id'";
```

This has an additional advantage over your code. When using select/update there is a chance that something else modifies quantity between the select and the update. With your code, this modification could be lost since it will be overwritten by the update query. Using a single query guarantees that this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE item_id = '$id'";
```

You can also use `+`, `*` and `/`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE items SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE item_id = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE item_id = '$id'";
```