# Update table with increment value

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

Im trying to update a value in a table, using while loop, but i want this value to be like using auto_inc key.

My table: `ID / CAR_ID / IMG_KEY / IMAGE`

i want to take 12 rows of the same `CAR_ID` and give the `IMG_KEY` values from 1-12.

I tried the below loops, but the result is giving the IMG_KEY the value 1

```
$getImages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM more_images WHERE car_id = '$car_id'") or die(mysql_error());  

$img_key = 0;
    for ($img_key = 1; $img_key <= mysql_num_rows($getImages); $img_key ++) {
        while ($selectedImages = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages)) {
            $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `more_images` SET `img_key` = '$img_key' WHERE `car_id` = '$car_id'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

The goal is give to the following 12 rows `img_key` values from 1 to 12 and all the other values as they are.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973380/sql-how-to-increase-or-decrease-one-for-a-int-column-in-one-command

Comment: As `$car_id` doesn't changes, you are updating always the same row.

Comment: You seem to be looping through selected rows to update them based on data in each row. Please post the SQL you use to select these rows as it looks like it can be done with the one SQL call and no looping over results.

Comment: Ooh, in your while-loop you're reading all the records returned, which in no way does anything to advance your for-loop. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you're best to switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. (Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: i updated the question for better explanation. i know about `mysql` decleration. My PHP is old. When i'll update it,i'll replace the `mysql` functions.Not now

Comment: Please show the query that selects those rows

Comment: What is the value of `mysql_num_rows($getImages)`?

Comment: @popnoodles the query results are in the pic

Comment: Please show the **query** that selects those rows

Comment: $getImages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `more_images` WHERE `car_id` = '$car_id'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @JohnPriestakos would you place that in your question? It allows people reading your question to understand it without having to sift through the comments.

Comment: Does my answer below do anything for you?

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes returns 1 again. Not 1-12

Comment: I've been wondering, how come you get `$img_key = 1` in your PHP, while your database results (in your screenshot) show `img_key = 2`?

Comment: I reset the value to 0 everytime i test the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm still not 100% sure what you want, but my guess is that you are looking for something like this:

```
$imgKey = 0;
while ($selectedImages = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages))
{
   $imgKey++;
   $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `more_images` SET `img_key` = '{$imgKey}' WHERE `car_id` = '{$car_id}'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

In your question, your `for` loop isn't doing anything other than looping, in your case it iterates twelve times.

Since `mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages)` is a function that loops through all rows in a set of results. So for each iteration of your `for` loop, it updates all records to have the same `$img_key`.

Also, really do refrain from using `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated. Read this thread:
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: This still returns `img_key` to 1 at all 12 rows. I tried it before posting the question

Comment: Ok, I'm at a loss here at the moment. At this point I would use `var_dump()` to determine where my code goes wrong. I'd start with using `var_dump($img_key)` inside your `while` loop, to determine whether that value is what you expect it to be and debug forth until you've found the problem. Sometimes small issues like this are caused by things you expect to go right.

Comment: Nothing with var_dump($img_key)