# How to add new value to database column without deleting old data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add data to mysql table without removing old data of that column

stock = 50
now i want to add 5 more
so i want to get result in table as: stock = 50+5 or stock=60 
how i can do this in SQL

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without removing old data of that column"?  How do you plan to change a value without changing the value?

Comment: You should learn how to INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL how to increase or decrease one for a int column in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973380/sql-how-to-increase-or-decrease-one-for-a-int-column-in-one-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple SQL statement

```
UPDATE myTable Set stock = stock + 5 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `update`:

```
update t
    set stock = stock + 5
    where <whatever condition fro the row you want to set>;
```